# How to share data models between mongo and typescript?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose

I have a folder structure for a Node.js backend and an Angular2+ frontend project, as below:

```
- src/
   - server/
   - client/
   - shared/
       - models/
```

Inside the models folder, I model the data in 2 files:

user.model.js (used by node.js) includes:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    createdAt: Date,
    lastLogin: Date,
    username: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastName: String,
    auth:{
       code: String,
       date: Date
    },
    files:[{
        type: String,
        objectID: String
    }],
    company: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' },
});
```

user.model.ts (used by angular) includes:

```
export interface User {
    createdAt: Date,
    lastLogin: Date,
    username: string,
    firstname: string,
    lastName: string,
    auth:{
       code: string,
       date: Date
    },
    files:[{
        type: string,
        objectID: string
    }],
    company: any
};
```

Node uses mongoose to read/write mongoDB documents according to `userSchema` and sends them to the Angular client. Angular expects the user to be of type `User` as described above.

Is there a way to avoid writing 2 models for the same data (1-mongoose schema  2-typescript interface)?

Is it possible to write one data model that is used by the mongoose schema and the typescript interface?

Comment: Can't answer your question but some food for thought: Nest.js is a node.js framework which supports Typescript and works well with Angular (app structure imitates Angular) so using Nest.js (or some other node.js framework with Typescript support) would allow you to create and maintain only one model for one type of data.

Comment: In addition, Nest.js supports Mongoose so no need to make any changes on that side. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb